# How to display java variable in javascript?

Tags: java, javascript, jsp, alert

```
  <%
  HttpSession s = request.getSession();
  s.setAttribute("user", userLogin.getUsername());
  String itemCode = (String) s.getAttribute("user");
  %>
<html>
<head>
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>MembersList</title>
<script>
function test()
{
    alert(<%out.println(itemCode);%>);
}
```

In my example, the alert does not appear.
I'm trying to print to the java variable in a javascript alert in a JSP page.

Comment: At least you are missing some quotes: `alert('<%out.println(itemCode);%>');`

Comment: Please show us the generated HTML code.

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
function test()
{
    alert('<%out.println(itemCode);%>');
}
```

Comment: I tried to do in 2 ways:
1)alert("<%out.println(itemCode);%>");
2)alert('<%out.println(itemCode);%>');
but does not work!

Comment: Are you calling the test function ?

Comment: Then try this `<%= itemCode %>`

Comment: No, it does not work. If I open the console of the browser it says when I call the function test (): "ReferenceError: testName is not defined". 
(testName is a name added by me).

Comment: And if you add `'` or `"` now ?

Comment: Perfect! Writing in this way it works: alert ('<% = ItemCode%>');

Comment: Pleased to help you :)

Answer (score 1):

You may be running into a problem with it creating a new line in the JavaScript alert call. Try this instead:

```
function test()
{
    alert('<%out.print(itemCode);%>');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to avoid scriptlets. Have you tried something like this,

```
function test()
{
    var testValue = ${itemCode};
    alert(testValue);
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

@Clever: you are missing quotes, try the below code:

```
alert('<%out.print(itemCode);%>');
```